# Unable to dynamically update 1st activity after back button press in android

Tags: android, android-intent

In my application, i have 2 screens A and B .A is the home screen and  B screen is a chat screen. 
B has text views dynamically adding to the screen. Now when i click the back button ie from B--> A . The B screen is still dynamically updating itself in background.

My issue is here , when i wish to again see B  from A-->B , my B screen stops updating/refreshing itself dynamically.

To see the updates , I need to do B-->A then A-->B  , then i see the missed updates.

For Example : This is my scenario : I am creating a chat application, I have a timer in my chat activity , which continues to receive messages from server till my application lifecycle. My chat screen keeps receiving updates from the server even when chat activity is not visible / in short in background. i populate these updates on the screen by adding textviews dynamically to the layout.

Step 1 : app launches , i reach chat screen , first time my screen works well and dynamically keeps updating my screen by adding new text views

Step 2 : I press back button when on the chat screen. Now i'm on home screen. In the meantime the timer in my chat activity continues  to receive server messages after every 10 sec.  (I am caching the data here).

Step 3 : I go back to my chat activity, i can successfully populate the cached data in step 2.  But now my chat activity is not dynamically updating the screen, even though my data is getting cached. When i debug i can see calls going to mylayout.addview(text view)...
however this new textview is not visible on screen

Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you create a *simple* example (well as simple as possible and no simpler) that illustrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi, i added my scenario and an example

Comment: Did you override onBackPressed in B?

Answer (score 0):

I was the issue with my timer..
Initialy i started my timer, once the user send the first msg to server.

strange ... but to resolve this issue I had to apply checks in oncreate() for my timer...
and it worked !!